# Pandas apply condition on a column that contains list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column based on a condition that have to be applied on a list. Here's a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "BRAND": [[], ["LVH"], ["FER", "MER", "POR"], ["WDC", "AUD", "LVH"], ["AST"]]
    }
)
print(df)
   ID            BRAND
0   1               []
1   2            [LVH]
2   3  [FER, MER, POR]
3   4  [WDC, AUD, LVH]
4   5            [AST]
```

As one can see, each object in the `BRAND` column is a list that can contain one or more elements (the list can also be empty as for the row where `ID = 1`).

Now, given the following target list `target_list = ["LVH", "WDC"]`, my goal is to create a new column based on the following rule: if at least one element of `target_list` (i.e. either `LVH` or `WDC`) is present in the `BRAND` column value, then assign a flag equal to `Y` in a new column (otherwise assign `N`). The resulting DataFrame for the above example should look as follows:

```
   ID            BRAND FLAG
0   1               []    N
1   2            [LVH]    Y
2   3  [FER, MER, POR]    N
3   4  [WDC, AUD, LVH]    Y
4   5            [AST]    N
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Seems to be a bit faster on a larger set than Option 2 below:

```
df['FLAG'] = df.BRAND.explode().isin(target_list).groupby(level=0, sort=False)\
    .any().map({True:'Y',False:'N'})

print(df)

   ID            BRAND FLAG
0   1               []    N
1   2            [LVH]    Y
2   3  [FER, MER, POR]    N
3   4  [WDC, AUD, LVH]    Y
4   5            [AST]    N
```

*Explanation:*

- Use [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to "[t]ransform each element of a list-like to a row".
- Check for matches with [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), and get `True` or `False`.
- We now have a series with duplicate rows, so use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) to isolate the groups, apply [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html), and get a `pd.Series` back with booleans in the correct shape.
- Finally, use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to turn `False` and `True` into `"N"` and `"Y"` respectively.

**Option 2**:

Basically same performance as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73966839/18470692) by [@AnoushiravanR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14314520/anoushiravan-r)

```
df['FLAG'] = df.BRAND.apply(lambda x: 'Y' if len(set(x) & set(target_list)) 
                            else 'N')

print(df)

   ID            BRAND FLAG
0   1               []    N
1   2            [LVH]    Y
2   3  [FER, MER, POR]    N
3   4  [WDC, AUD, LVH]    Y
4   5            [AST]    N
```

*Explanation:* `set(list_a) & set(list_b)` being a shorthand for [`set_a.intersection(set_b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection), which we pass to `len()`. If `len(...) == 0`, this will result in `False`.

Comment: It is very interesting to know that these two are equivalent. Because at the beginning it looks like if both sets are not empty the if statement should return True.

Answer (score 1):

Another very similar approach could be:

```
df['Flag'] = df.BRAND.transform(lambda x: 'Y' if any(mot in x for mot in ['LVH', 'WDC']) else 'N')

   ID            BRAND Flag
0   1               []    N
1   2            [LVH]    Y
2   3  [FER, MER, POR]    N
3   4  [WDC, AUD, LVH]    Y
4   5            [AST]    N
```